# JavaScript - how to get file id attribute of more than 1 files?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript function that I wrote:

```
function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
            alert("Please select at least one file.");
            return false;
        }

        var fileID = $(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');

      /*  var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        $fileChecks.each(function() {
            var file = $(this).attr('fileid');
            alert(file+"has been selected");
        });
        var count = $fileChecks.length;*/



        $('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {

            nodeID:fileID

            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });



    }catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }


}
```

When I checked on tick box on any files and fire the GENURL button, the function above is called. Below is a screenshot of my screen:

[image: Screenshot]

And it calls `genurl.jsp` which retrives the fileID of the ticked checkbox.

GENURL.JSP:

```
  <%

    //grabs the file id of each file
    long nodeID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("nodeID"));





        //need to input logic to populate data on each row
        int count = 0;

        List files = fileFacade.list_items(nodeID);
        for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
            Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
            Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
           // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());


            count++;




    %>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%">
    <!-- Checkbox   -->
                <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;
            </td>

            <td>

                <!-- No   -->

            </td>
            <td width="28%">

                <!-- Filename   -->
                <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>
            </td>


        </tr>

        </tbody>


    <%}
    %>
```

As you can see `nd.getNodedesc` will return the file name and populate my jsp page table.

Anyway, it works if I checked one box and populate the table but how do I make it retrieve multiple file ID's if ticked more than once and populate the table?

I know this line `var fileID = $(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');` only retrieves one file ID but I can't figure how to get multiple files to pass it to the JSP page.

### Edit

In my JavaScript function, under the code that is commented out, that snippet is able to retrieve multiple file id but it's unable to pass the value to `data`.

```
function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
            alert("Please select at least one file.");
            return false;
        }

        cutFiles = new Object();

        var count = 0;
        for(var file in selectedItems){
            var fileID = file.substring(0);

            // post each selected fileID
            cutFiles['fileID' + count] = fileID;
            count += 1;
            alert(fileID +" has been selected");
        }




       // var fileID = $(selectedFiles[0]).attr('fileid');

      /*  var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        $fileChecks.each(function() {
            var file = $(this).attr('fileid');
            alert(file+"has been selected");
        });
        var count = $fileChecks.length;*/



        $('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {

            nodeID:fileID

            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });



    }catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }


}
```

### Edit 4

```
 String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
 for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

     long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way how you can pass array via HTML GET in JS using single data variable that I know, is to somehow stringify it:

```
var selectedFiles = [];
$('.fileCheck:checked').each(function() { selectedFiles.push($(this).attr('fileid')); });
var stringArray = JSON.stringify(selectedFiles);

$('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {

            nodeID:stringArray 

            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });
```

This will send a string that can be parsed into array with:

```
JSON.parse(request.getParameter("nodeID"));
```

See Fiddle example what output does it produce.

https://jsfiddle.net/h3Legzt6/1/

EDIT:

There are some limitations tho:
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

Other way how to do it is using local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('IDs', JSON.stringify(selectedFiles));
```

and

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('IDs'));
```

This also has limitations but is limited to much more space, based on a browser default settings. Unfortunately this space is not guaranteed as users can configure how much space can localStorage take. [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

Also, be careful as mutiple tabs can interfere with this storage and including some call identification in storage name, unique for each tab name would be a good idea and provding this unique ID to JSP so it will be able to find it.

EDIT2:

To implement it into your code this should do:

```
function fireGENURL(a){
    try{

        var selectedFiles = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        if(selectedFiles.length < 1 ){
            alert("Please select at least one file.");
            return false;
        }

        var filesList = [];
        var $fileChecks = $('.fileCheck:checked');
        $fileChecks.each(function() {
            filesList.push($(this).attr('fileid'));
        });
        var count = $fileChecks.length;
        var stringArray = JSON.stringify(filesList);



        $('body').pWin("open", {
            x: 260,
            y: 47,
            height: 450,
            width: 881,
            title: "Generate URL",
            skinMode:'dialog',
            iframe:true,
            url: "file/url/genurl.jsp",
            data: {

            nodeID:stringArray

            },
            offResize:true,
            offMove:true,
            onTitle:false,
            offBottom:true
        });



    }catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }


}
```

EDIT 3:

As per comments, it is also possible to generate a string of delimited numbers (ex.: 123,234) and split them in JSP and convert them to Long in loop.

EDIT 4:

This is just an attempt and syntax might be wrong, you got it almost there I think. You split, loop trough it and convert to Long and this long can be used with the rest of the code:

```
<%

    String[] split = request.getParameter("nodeID").split(",",0);
     for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++){

         long file=Long.parseLong(split[i]);

        //need to input logic to populate data on each row
        int count = 0;

        List files = fileFacade.list_items(file);
        for (Iterator rstltr = files.iterator(); rstltr.hasNext();) {
            Fmedia fv = (Fmedia) rstltr.next();
            Node nd = nodeFacade.get(fv.getNodeid(), false);
           // Fmedia fm = fileFacade.get_file(fv.getNodeid());


            count++;




    %>

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="5%">
    <!-- Checkbox   -->
                <input type="checkbox" name="name1" />&nbsp;
            </td>

            <td>

                <!-- No   -->

            </td>
            <td width="28%">

                <!-- Filename   -->
                <%=nd.getNodedesc()%>
            </td>


        </tr>

        </tbody>


    <%}}
    %>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189626/discussion-on-answer-by-kayanatsumi-javascript-how-to-get-file-id-attribute-of).